# Adicionar mais de um append no http header angular

Tags: angular, http, interceptor

Estou fazendo um `Interceptor` que deve adicionar no meu cabeçalho um *token* e um authorization sempre que o valor de `authToken` for diferente de nulo.
Meu problema está em como adicionar um `append` no meu cabeçalho.

Tentei algo como:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if(authToken != null){
        const newRequest = req.clone({
            setHeaders: { Authorization: `bearer ${authToken}` }
        });
        return next.handle(newRequest);
    }else{
        const newRequest = req.clone({});
        return next.handle(newRequest);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Realmente um mistério! O único ponto que posso imaginar pode ser com o retorno do localStorage pode estar vindo diferente de null.

Comment: Não parece ter nada errado com o código, eu recomendaria apenas colocar o bearer com B maiúsculo dessa forma => Bearer, se não for assim há uma chance grande a api responder com 401, pois é case sensitive. Você saberia dizer se o Token está pelo menos sendo passado no aba network do developer console?